# Is embedding a UIViewController better than adding a subview to a UIViewController (programmatically)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, embedding

What's the difference between adding a `viewcontroller`'s view inside another `view controller`'s view and embedding a view controller like this:

```
 addChildViewController(controller)

 self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
 controller.view.frame = view.bounds
 controller.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

 controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding a view controller (View Controller Containment) has added benefits such as calls being made to `viewDidAppear`, `viewDidDisappear` and rotation and resizing events being passed to the view controller to handle. These don't happen when you just add a view directly.

Comment: Thank you, and do you know if it’s possible to embed a viewcontroller inside a collection view header?